# AWS Lambda POST to DynamoDB with APIGateway in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on API to POST data into DynamoDB using AWS API gateway and AWS Lambada. The problem is when I use the test scenario is working fine but not the same in Postman or any other outside AWS API services.

```
import boto3
import uuid

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # this will create dynamodb resource object and
    # here dynamodb is resource name
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    title = event['title']
    #generte UUID 
    recordId = str(uuid.uuid4())

    # this will search for dynamoDB table 
    # your table name may be different
    table = client.Table("smsapi")
    print(table.table_status)

    #Creating an Item with a unique id and with the passed title
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'id' : recordId,
            'title' : title
        }
    )

    return recordId
```

In Postman I receive 502 Bad gateway

[image: POSTMAN API - response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A probable reason is that API Gateway proxy integration uses different format of `event` as compared when you test your function in lambda console.

The format [is](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format):

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {String containing incoming request headers}
    "multiValueHeaders": {List of strings containing incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {List of query string parameters}
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

Whatever payload you submit through API gateway will be in:

- "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."

So in your lambda function you need to parse the `body` payload.

Answer (score 0):

This message is pretty much common when you have some issues with integration, something like the luck of permissions, wrong format, etc.
So, I won't give you the reason, I'll show you how to find this issue.
You can test such integration using the AWS Console. Go to your API in API Gateway page, choose a method you want to test and click Test button on the left:
[image]
Here you can send test request with all required parameters and see the detailed log of the integration flow. Usually, the error message will be somewhere at the bottom of the log. You can also find a lot of details here, like what was request and response before transformation and so on.
[image]